# I Have Csv File, having statusid,comanyid.I need to get the statusid and compare the status id , based on the id companies should execute

Tags: jmeter

[I Have Csv File, having statusid,comanyid.I need to get the statusid and compare the status id , based on the id companies should execute.
Below is the csv file. can any one suggest how it can be done with piece of beanshell code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvGAb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve the issue , by using simple IF controller and passing ${JobId}='13'for each controller with respective condition. its working